# How to securely apply truststore and keystore password to JConsole configuration

Tags: java, keystore, jmx, jconsole, truststore

I am using JConsole to securely connect to a remote JMX endpoint on another machine. 
I am doing my best to use TLS every step of the process, and this includes having the hosts authenticate each other. I have done this by importing each's certificate into the other's truststore

I have gotten all of this to work correctly, with jconsole now being launched with:

```
jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/trustStore -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

However, I do not like this solution as I am now supplying passwords on the commandline, making it readily readable by anyone with access to the host or our monitoring tools.

I fixed this issue with the accompanying java application by specifying the location of ssl config file, where the passwords and paths to keystores are kept:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.config.file=/path/to/ssl_config ...
```

However, this does not work with jconsole. I have not even received any indication that the config file is even being referenced or read. I have tried numerous ways to reference a config file, and tried to get jconsole to read the passwords from a file, but none will work.

Does anyone know of a way to supply passwords to jconsole without supplying them in plaintext on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass *-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=PASSFILE* where PASSFILE is the file name and contains the user name/password pair, space separated.

See https://gquintana.github.io/2016/09/01/Securing-remote-JMX.html

Comment: That option is used for the java application that is exposing the JMX endpoint. I am trying to connect to the endpoint with jconsole, wherein I will supply my organizational credentials to authenticate to that host. The truststore and keystore passwords are used to access the keystores so jconsole can verify the remote host's identity and my application can verify the host connecting to it via its certificate